# How would you do that opening effect with React Native?

Tags: react-native

Imagine a feed of items and then you click on one item and it opens in this way. We need  to create a news app that has this identical animation (check sec 00:13 of video linked). [enter link description here](https://figmenta.dev/slideup.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react-native-collapsible package to achieve something like this
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to do dynamic styling.

like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";


const Component = () => {
  const [isOpen, setisOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setisOpen(!isOpen)}>
      <View>
          {/* The View content that is always open */}
      </View>


      <View style={isOpen ? { disply: "flex" } : { disply: "none" }}>
        {/* The View content to be opened/hidden */}
      </View>

      
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

then you can just import this component in your screen like this:

```js
<Component  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Depend on the navigation library you are using but I will assume that you are using `react-navigation`.

You have this package to perform an animation with shared element during navigation between two screens: https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-navigation-shared-element.

Very easy to use and very performant.